# Ruby on Rails - Adding morris.js Correctly for a associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, morris.js

In my application I have models `Campaign` & `Map`:

```
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :maps, :dependent => :destroy

class Map < ActiveRecord::Base
  is_impressionable :counter_cache => true, :unique => :request_hash
  belongs_to :campaign, :counter_cache => true, touch: true
```

In my `Map` model, I'm using **`is_impressionable`** that comes with installing **`impressionist gem`** & I have added `counter_cache` as well that will update my `impressions_count` for every visit *(in my `maps` table)*.

In my `campaigns#show` view, Im trying to add a chart for `maps impressions` by using **morris.js** *(I have added all needed files in my application and can see the chart)*.

In my chart, I want to show `impressions` on `campaign.maps`, but I am getting wrong data into my chart.

So basically, go to my `impressions` table, and `sum` all visits that my `campaign.maps` has on the giving day.

*This is what I have until now:*

```
module CampaignsHelper
  def impressions_chart_data_campaign(maps)
    (7.days.ago.to_date..Date.today).map do |date|
      {
          created_at: date,
          impressions: Impression.where("date(created_at) =?", date).where(id: maps).size
      }
    end
  end
end
```

*My `campaigns#show` view:*

```
= content_tag :div, "", id: "impressions_charts_double", data: {impressions: impressions_chart_data_campaign(@campaign.maps)}

:javascript
  Morris.Area({
    element: 'impressions_charts_double',
    data: $('#impressions_charts_double').data('impressions'),
    xkey: 'created_at',
    ykeys: ['impressions'],
    labels: ['Impressions']
  });
```

As mentioned I am getting completely wrong numbers. This is queries in my console:

[image: DB Queries]
I'm not sure What Im doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line looks suspect:

```
impressions: Impression.where("date(created_at) =?", date).where(id: maps).size
```

The `where(id: maps)` is selecting on the `id` column for impressions, whereas you presumably want to be selecting on `impressionable_type` and `impressionable_id`?

Comment: OMG!! Thanks @gwcodes, This is what happens when your eyes are tired and you are out of focus haha.